# How can I get only one digit as an argument of the main function?

Tags: c, function, cs50

I have a problem with isdigit(). For an exercise, I need to pass only a numerical value to the main function. 
This means that I cannot pass "3 4 5" neither "hello". My code is properly working with these examples but it's not working with the value "2x" even though it's working with the value "x2".

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    if ((argc == 2) && isdigit(*argv[1]))
    {
        printf("%s \n", argv[1]);
        printf("%i \n", argc);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You have to use only one numeric value \n");
    }
}
```

I tried to change `if ((argc == 2) && isdigit(*argv[1]))` into `if ((argc == 2) && isdigit(argv[1]))` but I keep getting `Segmentation fault`.

Could you please help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `if ((argc == 2) && isdigit(*argv[1]) && (argv[1][1] == '\0'))`

Comment: What happens when you declare main as `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and access the argument with `if ((argc == 2) && isdigit(*argv[1]))` ?

Comment: @DavidRanieri solution worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit(int character)` checks only one value. You can see that because you have to pass `*argv[1]` being the first character of the second element in `argv`. The first character of `2x` is `2` so your program behaves as expected.

What you could do is get the length of the input using `strlen(argv[1])` and then use a loop to check whether all characters in the string are digits. This however only works for decimal integers.